# Orders and quotes with client register in django

Tags: django, dom

```
`HTML:

`{% csrf_token %} {{ form | crispy }}
<select id="id_cliente" name="cliente" onchange="update_cliente_data()">
                    <option value="">Selecione um cliente...</option>
                    {% for cliente in clientes %}
                        {% with cliente_data=cliente.to_json %}
                        <option id="opcao" value="{{ cliente.id }}" data-cliente="{% for key, value in cliente_data.items %}'{{ key }}': '{{ value|escapejs }}',{% endfor %}">{{ cliente.nome }}</option>
                        {% endwith %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>`

SCRIPT: 

`<script>
    // Chamar a função update_cliente_data() quando o DOM é carregado
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        console.log('DOM carregado.');
        update_cliente_data();
    });

    function update_cliente_data() {
        var clienteSelect = document.getElementById('id_cliente');
        if (clienteSelect) {
            var selectedIndex = clienteSelect.selectedIndex;
            if (selectedIndex !== -1) {
                var clienteOption = clienteSelect.options[selectedIndex];
                //var clienteOpcao = document.getElementById('opcao');
                var clienteDataAttr = clienteOption.getAttribute('data-cliente');
                //var clienteDataAttr = clienteOpcao.getAttribute('data-cliente');
                if (clienteDataAttr) {
                    try {
                        var clienteData = JSON.parse(clienteDataAttr);
                        document.getElementById('id_nome').value = clienteData.nome;
                        document.getElementById('id_cpf').value = clienteData.cpf;
                        document.getElementById('id_email').value = clienteData.email;
                        document.getElementById('id_rg').value = clienteData.rg;
                        document.getElementById('id_cidade').value = clienteData.cidade;
                        document.getElementById('id_telefone').value = clienteData.telefone;
                        document.getElementById('id_numero').value = clienteData.numero;
                        document.getElementById('id_rua').value = clienteData.rua;
                        document.getElementById('id_bairro').value = clienteData.bairro;
                    } catch (error) {
                        console.error('Erro ao analisar os dados do cliente:', error);
                    }
                } else {
                    console.error('Atributo "data-cliente" não encontrado no elemento selecionado.');
                }
            } else {
                console.error('Nenhum item selecionado no select.');
            }
        } else {
            console.error('Elemento com ID "id_cliente" não encontrado no DOM.');
        }
    }
</script>``
```

It all seems correctly for me, but the attribute 'data-cliente' isn't beeing found by the console, can someone help me? It is for a college project and it's very important. Sorry for the portuguese comments and variables btw

Answer (score 0):

Here is working [example](https://jsfiddle.net/4p9oLgk0/3/), just make sure that your resulted html the same.

There's a small issue with your Django template that's preventing the attribute 'data-cliente' from being recognized correctly. In your for-loop, you are serializing a JSON object, but you are not closing the JSON object properly.

This part of your code:

```html
data-cliente="{% for key, value in cliente_data.items %}'{{ key }}': '{{ value|escapejs }}',{% endfor %}"
```

Is outputting this (example):

```html
data-cliente="'nome': 'John Doe','cpf': '1234567890',"
```

The problem is that your JSON object is not properly formatted and is missing opening `{` and closing `}` brackets.

Here's the corrected version:

```html
data-cliente="{ {% for key, value in cliente_data.items %}'{{ key }}': '{{ value|escapejs }}',{% endfor %} }"
```

But, the above version still might create an issue due to the trailing comma at the end of the last item. To avoid this, you can build your JSON object in a slightly different way. You should consider using the `json_script` filter provided by Django to output safe JSON in your HTML.

This is how you can do it:

```html
{% with cliente_data=cliente.to_json %}
    <option id="opcao" value="{{ cliente.id }}" data-cliente="{{ cliente_data|json_script:'clienteData' }}">{{ cliente.nome }}</option>
{% endwith %}
```

Make sure to load the `static` and `escapejs` filters in your template if not loaded:

```html
{% load static escapejs %}
```

Lastly, don't forget to parse this 'data-cliente' attribute value in your JavaScript code as it is a stringified JSON object:

```js
var clienteData = JSON.parse('{' + clienteDataAttr + '}');
```

Please ensure that the `to_json` method you're using in your Django template does provide a dictionary because `json_script` requires it.

Let me know if this helps or if you have any other questions!

Comment: I've followed all the tips. I can see on the console that all the data is in 'data-cliente' attribute, but the error is still happening: the attribute isn't beeing found

Comment: I've built a working [example](https://jsfiddle.net/4p9oLgk0/3/) make sure that your data attribute using "'", and json inside using '"' like in example.

Also, please avoid to use same id for each option, you can pase forloop.index to the end of the value.

Just check that you html looks like my.